# Ask CATextLayer on top of mask layer

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

In my app, I have added a mask to a UIImageView, and set it at half opacity. Also, there is a CAAnimation running on that CALayer.

Now, I want to add a CATextLayer on top of it all, and it must NOT be affected by the mask layer. How can I do this?

Thanks

EDIT: A new problem has arised. Somehow, if a message to the CATextLayer is send in animationDidStart, the animations are performed in reverse order.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
    NSString* intValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];

    animation.duration = 0.5;

    animation.delegate = self;

    animation.repeatCount = 0;

    animation.autoreverses = NO;

    [animation setValue:intValue forKey:@"animationString"];

    animation.timingFunction = nil;

    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

    animation.fromValue = (id) [self getCGRectForZoomLevel:i];

    animation.toValue = (id) [self getCGRectForZoomLevel:i + 1 ];

    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + i * 2;

    [self.shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:intwaarde];


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Because I had put the animations in 
    `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

everything went wrong. I'd put it in that method because it was someone else's project from github originally.

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your hierarchy.

Add a view as a container to group the image view and the text layer so that they are siblings (compared to now when the text layer is a sublayer of the image view)

Then mask the image view just like you are already doing.

```
Container   // ⬅ this one is new
   ┃
   ┣━━ Image view ┅ (mask)
   ┃
   ┗━━ Text layer // ⬅ is now a sibling
```

Comment: @Rönnqvist Thanks David! However, I would like to update this Text Layer when an animation is about to start, as in: '- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation
{
    
     self.textLayer.string =  [theAnimation valueForKey:@"animationString"];
     
}'

Comment: What is it that add the animation to the layer? You can still become the delegate of an animation and use `animationDidStart:` to react to it. The question is just where you should be the delegate

Comment: That is exactly what I do and animationDidStart is indeed called. However, the call to self.textLayer in    - (void)animationDidStart somehow cancels the animation that is about to start. self.textLayer is NOT the layer that the animation is playing in.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated. When creating the animation I use: `[animation setValue:textString forKey:@"animationString"];` Then, in animationDidStart: I try to retrieve the animationString value by `self.textLayer.string = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"animationString"].` Somehow this doesn't work

Comment: That should be unrelated to the hierarchy. How does it fail? Does it get called at all? Is the animation nil? Is the value nil?

Comment: Yes, `animationDidStart` gets called. The animation is not nil. The value is not nil either. What I noticed: if I put `self.textLayer.string = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"animationString"]` in animationDidStart, the animations are fired in reverse order! Maybe it has to do with how the animations are added in a for loop: `animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + i * 2;`

Comment: That should also be completely unrelated to the hierarchy. How are you adding the animations to the layer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30333/discussion-between-rudolf-j-and-david-ronnqvist)